# Indirect way of usine Model.objects.all() in a formset

Tags: python, django

I'm using something like this to populate inlineformsets for an update view:

```
formset = inline_formsetfactory(Client, Groupe_esc, form=GroupEscForm, formset=BaseGroupEscInlineFormset, extra=len(Groupe.objects.all()))
```

(Basically I need as many extra form as there are entries in that table, for some special processing I'm doing in `class BaseGroupEscInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormset))`.

That all works fine, BUT if I pull my code & try to `makemigrations` in order to establish a brand new DB, that line apparently fails some django checks and throws up a `"no such table (Groupe)"` error and I cannot `makemigrations`. Commenting that line solves the issues (then I can uncomment it after making migration). But that's exactly best programming practices.

So I would need a way to achieve the same result (determine the extra number of forms based on the content of Groupe table)... but without triggering that django check that fails. I'm unsure if the answer is django-ic or pythonic.

E.g. perhaps I could so some python hack that allows me to specific the classname without actually importing Groupe, so I can do `my_hacky_groupe_import.Objects.all()`, and maybe that wouldn't trigger the error?

EDIT:

In forms.py:

```
from .models import Client, Groupe
class BaseGroupEscInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        """ this BaseInlineFormset method returns kwargs provided to the form.
            in this case the kwargs are provided to the GroupEsForm constructor
        """
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
        try:
            group_details = kwargs['group_details'][index]
        except Exception as ex:                                    # likely this is a POST, but the data is already in the form
            group_details = []
        return {'group_details':group_details}



GroupeEscFormset = inlineformset_factory(Client, Groupe_esc,
                                         form=GroupeEscForm,
                                         formset=BaseGroupEscInlineFormset,
                                         extra=len(Groupe.objects.all()),
                                         can_delete=False)
```

Comment: Write that line in a function / method (basically somewhere it won't get run when the file is imported)

Comment: Can you show where you implemented that. Usually the best way to fix this is work with a `get_formset` method (that the view/viewset/... usually offers), and make the query at *that* level, not at a class level.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay, I'm not sure how to do that to be honest, but I see your point. Maybe that should be done in the view instead. I'm also unsure if that would would ever be udpated (beyond server start/restart I guess)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think that would actually do the trick. Probably the simplest (python) answer. However if there's a better django way to do this I'm be happy to work with the framework, rahter than around it...

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions you have already arrived at the answer, just write the line in the view.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not directly but it does provide useful background & explanation as to what happen.  I'm facepalming a little - e.g. why didn't I see that this was, in fact, written at the module level? At any rate, when you say "write the line in the view", do you mean to declare the GroupeEscFormset in the view? Or just the method that gets me the # of items in the table more likely?

Comment: You can do either, writing `GroupeEscFormset = inlineformset_factory(...)` directly in the view would be simpler. Otherwise you can keep it on the module level and set a default value for the `extra` and override `__init__` and accept it as a value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue as already outlined is that your code is written at the module level and it executes a query when the migrations are not yet done, giving you an error.

One solution as I already pointed in the comment would be to write the line to create the formset class in a view, example:

```
def some_view(request):
    GroupeEscFormset = inlineformset_factory(
        Client,
        Groupe_esc,
        form=GroupeEscForm,
        formset=BaseGroupEscInlineFormset,
        extra=len(Groupe.objects.all()),
        can_delete=False
    )
```

Or if you want some optimization and want to keep this line at the module level to not keep recreating this formset class, you can override the `__init__` method and accept `extra` as an argument (basically your indirect way to call `Model.objects.all()`):

```
class BaseGroupEscInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, extra=3, **kwargs):
        self.extra = extra
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...


GroupeEscFormset = inlineformset_factory(Client, Groupe_esc,
                                         form=GroupeEscForm,
                                         formset=BaseGroupEscInlineFormset,
                                         can_delete=False)


# In your views:
def some_view(request):
    formset = GroupeEscFormset(..., extra=Groupe.objects.count()) # count is better if the queryset is needed only to get a count
```